# Слайд из фотографий загружаемых из базы данных

Tags: javascript, html, python, css, django

Делаю интернет магазин, сделал отдельную страницу с описанием товара , хочу чтобы фотографии загружаемые из бд (у каждого товара 3 фото) были в слайдшоу. Приложил фото как щас выглядит [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Приложил код как достаю циклом картинки из бд , через views

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                {% for image_item in product.productimage_set.all %}
                       <div class="product-image-item">
                            <img src="{{ image_item.image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
                       </div>
                     {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

Код из Views

```
def product(request, product_id):
product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
return render(request, 'products/product.html', locals())
```

Таблица товара связана с таблицей картинок на каждый товар

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с использованием карусели bootstrap. Подключите библиотеку бутсрап и все будет работать.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carouselnews" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          {% for image_item in product.productimage_set.all %} 
          {% if forloop.first %}
          <div class="carousel-item active ">
            <div class="product-image-item">
              <img src="{{ image_item.image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
          </div>
          {% else %}
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="product-image-item">
              <img src="{{ image_item.image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endif %} 
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```